# Google Apps Script: Unable to Access Elements of Returned Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

### Problem

Unable to access just the numbers of a returned object. Getting commas and can't seem to stop this behavior.

### Current Outcome

```
    goalList = data[i][3].toString(); -> [2,10,3,4];
    var goal1 = goalList[0]; -> 2
    var goal2 = goalList[2]; -> 1
    var goal3 = goalList[4]; -> ,
    var goal4 = goalList[6]; -> ,
```

### Desired Outcome

```
    goalList = data[i][3].toString(); -> [2,10,3,4];
var goal1 = goalList[0]; -> 2
var goal2 = goalList[2]; -> 10
var goal3 = goalList[4]; -> 3
var goal4 = goalList[6]; -> 4
```

### Workflow

I have a function that returns the values that are in a spreadsheet. The getReportData() is being passed an array with 4 elements.

```
var profileList = getIds(processId);

if (profileList.length == 0) {
  processStatus = "Completed";
  ctrlRange.setValues([[processId, processStatus]]);
} else {
  getReportData(profileList, processId);
}
} catch(error) {
 Browser.msgBox(error.message);
 }
}
 function getIds(curPid) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Filtered Views');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var profilecmsArray = []

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pid = data[i][3];
    if (pid != curPid) {
      profilecmsArray.push([data[i][1], data[i][2], i+1, data[i][4]]);
    }
  }  
  return profilecmsArray;
}

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 profileId = data[i][0];
 clientCms = data[i][1];    
 goalList = data[i][3].toString();


 var goal1 = 'ga:goal' + newGoal[0] + 'Completions'
 var goal2 = 'ga:goal' + newGoal[2] + 'Completions'
 var goal3 = 'ga:goal' + newGoal[4] + 'Completions'
 var goal4 = 'ga:goal' + newGoal[6] + 'Completions'

 Logger.log(goal1);
 Logger.log(goal2);
 Logger.log(goal3);
 Logger.log(goal4);
```

Comment: In your script, ``data`` is retrieved at ``var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();``. So can you provide a sample spreadsheet or sample data? If the condition of cell, which values are stored, can be seen, it may approach to solutions.

Comment: Antoine, thanks for reaching out! Essentially, there are 4 columns, 2 rows.       H&H Buick GMC - Filtered 154548134 CDK  2,10,3,6
Cox Toyota - Filtered 130034109 DealerFire  1,5,10,11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is converting the array to a string instead of converting each element to a separate string. As an array, the first **element** of `[2,10,3,6]` would be 2, then 10, then 3, then 6. As a string, the first **character** of `2,10,3,6` is `2` then `,` then `1` then `0` then `,` then `3` then `,` then `6`.

To correct, try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 profileId = data[i][0];
 clientCms = data[i][1];    
 goalList = data[i][3];


 var goal1 = 'ga:goal' + goalList[0].toString() + 'Completions'
 var goal2 = 'ga:goal' + goalList[1].toString() + 'Completions'
 var goal3 = 'ga:goal' + goalList[2].toString() + 'Completions'
 var goal4 = 'ga:goal' + goalList[3].toString() + 'Completions'
```

Comment: Antoine, thanks for reaching out! The log says this: [17-12-14 07:50:40:913 EST] 2,10,3,6.

Comment: Found the problem! your code is getting a string a bit too early. It is taking `2,10,3,6` as a string, not an array. As an array, the first **element** would be 2, then 10, then 3, then 6. As a string, the first **character** is `2`, then `,` then `1` then `0` then `,` then `3` then `,` then `6`. Will update my answer in a few seconds.

Comment: @Mr.Beardface My answer is updated, let me know if my solution works!

Comment: Antoine, thanks for the help! I did try what you said, but it returned this result: [17-12-14 09:08:46:791 EST] ga:goal2Completions
[17-12-14 09:08:46:791 EST] ga:goal1Completions
[17-12-14 09:08:46:792 EST] ga:goal,Completions
[17-12-14 09:08:46:792 EST] ga:goal,Completions

Comment: Tried to pull the numbers out of var data, however when I tried iterate, it reuturned this: Cannot call property length in object 2,10,3,6. It is not a function, it is "number".

Comment: goalList = data[i][3].toString()
   
   for(i = 0; i < goalList.length(); i++){
     Logger.log(goalList[i]);
   }

Comment: Ah I see! I edited my answer again with `goalList[0].toString()`. Does that work? If not I would need to see your full code.

Comment: Still not getting the right values. I've included the function that pulls the data from the spreadhsheet below. Do you think it has something to with the return statement? function getIds(curPid) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Filtered Views');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var profilecmsArray = []
  
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pid = data[i][3];
    if (pid != curPid) {
      profilecmsArray.push([data[i][1], data[i][2], i+1, data[i][4]]);
    }
  }  
  return profilecmsArray;
}

Comment: Could you send a link to your script file or a copy if it please?

Comment: no, I don't think the `2 -- 1 -- , -- ,` problem is caused by your return statement. Would you care to explain why you write `goalList[0]` `goalList[2]` `goalList[4]` `goalList[6]` and not simply `goalList[0]` `goalList[1]` `goalList[2]` `goalList[3]` ?

Comment: Due to the "comma issue", I had to request every second element from the array. The real problem started when I had an array with a 2-digit number. [1,2,3,4] - works fine. [1,10,2,4] - doesn't work.

Comment: Ok you should not do that. I changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: According to this article, https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/. Certain objects are immutable. Looks like the object I'm trying to change is just that. May have to use a 3rd party library to fix this issue.

Comment: Since I cannot see your script file, I have no idea what you are talking about. Please send a link.

Comment: Please send a link to a file such as [this](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1vIZdUSw8FNdGDJHJhy5eWHr3wRydHHw9A99sS1IfKnw_HVnZiH_3o3j2/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvF3Rr4DDiwc-12vXgqwarPeJEypxlIAk3ycOzliAjFSE7MslrqUzA8Dl1ovZoX_jSjN1W99MjBypihw1WcMXsMF8fWfsL6SyJY3yUCWjROOxFwgmUvyMyhXVoQAktruUWvWfCVwkrk&splash=yes)

Comment: Thanks for the links! How can I reproduce the problem? Is there supposed to be data in the spreadsheet? Which function should I run?

Comment: Antoine, figured it out. Had to change the object type to String before I could access the correct elements. Thanks for your help!